# Multiprocessing with if __name__ == '__main__':

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to call 1 main function which hands out options into other scripts. For example, my main.py will show "Select an option: 1,2,3,4,5". Once they press for example, 5, it will execute the script for #5, which is another python file.

My issues is, inside one of the scripts, I am doing multiprocessing and cannot get the function to start inside `if __name__ == "__main__":`.

I got the value of `__name__` and it's showing the name of my script `SCRIPT_NAME.py`. When I changed the name to `if __name__ == "SCRIPT_NAME":` it got inside the `if` statement, but then the multiprocessing doesn't actually work.

There is nothing wrong with my main.py code. It's just this multiprocessing script I have:

###### SCRIPT_NAME.py

```
def saveLogs()...

def goBackToMain()...

def newChecker()...

def mp_handler(p):
    global ALL_EMAILS
    p.map(newChecker, ALL_EMAILS)

if __name__ == "SCRIPT_NAME":
    
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()

    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    bad_list = manager.list()
    good_list = manager.list()

    # Foreach email, parse it into our checker
    # Define a filename to save to
    FILE_NAME_DATE_GOODS = '{}{}{}'.format(location_emails_goods, todayString, '.txt')
    FILE_NAME_DATE_BADS = '{}{}{}'.format(location_emails_bads, todayString, '.txt')

    file_bads = open(FILE_NAME_DATE_BADS, 'a')
    file_goods = open(FILE_NAME_DATE_GOODS, 'a')

    p = multiprocessing.Pool(1)

    mp_handler(p)

    saveLogs()

    p.close()

    goBackToMain()
else:
    print(__name__)
```

main.py

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, './scripts')

# Here we will make it selectable to pick an option to run
def wholeMain():
    OPTIONS = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five']

    print('\n')

    count = 1
    for option in OPTIONS:
        print('# [{}] = {}'.format(count, option))
        count += 1

    print('=============================')
    selection = input('\n# Select an option to start:')

    if int(selection) == 1:
        
        import ONE
    elif int(selection) == 2:
        
        import TWO
    elif int(selection) == 3:
        
        import THREE
    elif int(selection) == 4:
        
        import FOUR
    elif int(selection) == 5:
        
        import FIVE
    else:
        print('# You did NOT select an option... please select an option and try again')
        return main()

wholeMain()
```

Comment: Windows? It can be an arse with multiprocessing. Wait a sec...
Looking at my scripts, on spyder, I have a "__spec__ == None" line inside the __main__":
Other than that, I'm able to call pool.apply_async() inside __main__: without problems.

Comment: @Amiga500 Yes, my issue i think  is because I am trying to run this file from another script.

Comment: You wrote "it will execute the script for #5, which is another python file".  How?  Please show the code from your `main.py`.  Using `if __name__ == <something other than __main__>` is not generally idiomatic in Python.  I think there is probably something wrong with your main.py, among other things.

Comment: @Iguananaut Just updated with my main.py

Comment: @ridentsmith Thanks.  As I suspected, you're using `import` statements to "run"  each "script" (which are essentially sub-routines or sub-commands).  So what you have is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) created from trying to solve an original problem (running sub-commands from some main script) in a way that is non-idiomatic, and thus creating new and different problems :)

Comment: I can suggest some different approaches, but one thing unclear from your originally question is, are your different "scripts" intended to be executable individually, or are they only ever run as sub-commands of your main front-end?

Comment: @Iguananaut well, If it works perfectly, I will only need to run from the main.py .

Comment: The are other things about the code you've shown that don't make a lot of sense.  For example, you are using multiprocessing.Pool with a pool size of 1 and calling `Pool.map` which blocks until completion.  This confers absolutely no advantage over just calling `map()` in the main process, unless this is something you intend to modify later.  Is that the case?  Also using function calls as a goto mechanism is unusual.  There's various other reasons this won't work like this (e.g. module imports are cached)

Comment: @Iguananaut My bad, I set the pools to 1 just as a test to see what was causing the issue. It was at 500 before, for alot of threads.

Comment: Spawning 500 processes is probably not going to give you much advantage either.  It would probably take longer to spawn that many processes than it would take to do whatever they're doing, and unless you have a machine with 500 CPUs and infinite I/O bandwidth...

Answer (score 0):

In short, as mentioned in the comments, your code has several problems.

Most of the trouble is in fact in your `main.py`.  Importing a module containing module-level code is not a good way to run a sub-routine, for many reasons, but not the least of which is the fact that imports are cached globally, so `import ONE`, for example, will only run the code in the `ONE` module once, no matter how many times you re-run `wholeMain()`.  This is true even for in-line imports.

There are many possible ways to go about structuring code like this, so I will just give one suggestion which is simple and straightforward:

First, in each of your sub-modules (`ONE`, `TWO`, etc.) move the code you have at module-level into a function.  You can call it `main()` or `run()` or whatever you want.  Let's call it `run()`.

So in `ONE.py` you would have:

```
def run():
    # Do whatever the 1. command does, you can use multiprocessing or
    # whatever
```

There is no need for doing anything with `if __name__ ==`  in these sub-modules.  That incantation is only necessary if you're starting a multiprocessing.Pool from the `__main__` module of a script.

In fact, in each of your sub-modules you could add something like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

to make those modules executable as stand-alone scripts, but it's not necessary.

In `main.py` you can import each sub-module individually:

```
import ONE
import TWO
...
```

you can put these at the top of your module since now you've restructured these files not to run anything at import time.

Then, to simplify things in your "wholeMain()`function (which I'll just call`main()`) you could also define a dispatch table (this allows eliminating your big multi-branch` if` statement and is easier to expand later):

```
subcommands = {
    '1', ONE.run
    '2', TWO.run,
    '3', THREE.run,
    ...
    'q': sys.exit
}
```

(I would also give these modules better names, but maybe in your real code they already have different names).

Then in `main()` run a loop:

```
def main():
    while True:
        # print table of available options; you could also modify
        # the subcommands dict to include things like titles for each option
        option = input('\n# Select an option to start: ').strip().lower()

        if option not in subcommands:
            print('Not a valid option')
            continue

        subcommand = subcommands[option]
        subcommand()
```